# Java: Using user input, determin if one integer is lower/higher or equal to than another integer

Tags: java

I am new to java and have been learning the code using netbeans. After using tutorials and getting to grips of the basics, I set myself a task of :

**"Using user input, determine if one integer is  equal to another integer"**

I want the code to compare the two integers inputted by the user and to check if they are equal. if they are not equal it should say *they are not equal* but if the integers are equal the code should say *they are equal*

When I press run it all seems fine as the code doesn't show any errors but the output box comes up with this:

**java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=2][match valid=true][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\,][decimal separator=.][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q�\E][infinity string=\Q∞\E]is not equal tojava.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=2][match valid=true][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\,][decimal separator=.][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q�\E][infinity string=\Q∞\E]**

**Here is my current code:**

```
package mark_userinputtask;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Mark_UserInputTask {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner var1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner var2 = new Scanner(System.in);    

        System.out.println(var1.nextLine());
        System.out.println(var2.nextLine());

        if (var1 == var2){
            System.out.println(var1 + " is equal to " + var2);  
        } else {
            System.out.println(var1 + "is not equal to" + var2);
        }
```

*I would just like to know of anything that I am doing wrong and what how I could make it work.*

Comment: You are comparing the Scanner objects instead of the user input. Try to save the results of `nextLine()` in Strings and compare them using the `equals()` method

Comment: Can you add your part of code as a code, to make it more readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code fixed with in line comment explanations:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Mark_UserInputTask {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); //Declare the one scanner for the whole program

    System.out.print("Please enter your first integer: "); //Prompt the user for input
    int var1 = scanner.nextInt(); //Store the users input if it is an integer in a variable
    System.out.print("Please enter your second integer: "); 
    int var2 = scanner.nextInt(); 

    if (var1 == var2) { //test if both variables are equal
      System.out.println(var1 + " is equal to " + var2);
    } else {
      System.out.println(var1 + " is not equal " + var2);
    }
  }
}
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/FMAX/1)

Comment: You Lifesaver!! Cheers for the help mate :) At first it stated there was no class, but for some reason Netbeans didnt put in the "static void" part, after I put that in the code worked perfectly

Comment: Change `Main` to the name of your java file i.e. `Mark_UserInputTask` :)

Comment: Top Class help dude! :) If I could a 5 star review for you sir :)

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing object references, not values.
Try using the equals method.

```
String s1 = var1.nextLine();
String s2 = var2.nextLine();
if (s1.equals(s2)) { // true
   .
   .
   .

} else {  // false
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole thing you are doing is wrong, you assuming to compare two inputs by user but what you are comparing is two `Scanner` class instances.

You should store user input in some `int`variable and then compare like this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner var1 = new Scanner(System.in);

  int a = var1.nextInt();
  int b = var1.nextInt());

 if (a == b){ 
        System.out.println(a + " is equal to " +  b);

 } else {
    System.out.println(a + "is not equal to" + b);
 }
```

Also you don't have to use separate `Scanner` class instance for each user input.

Comment: Cheers for the code, Thanks for the help :) I have tried shash678's code and that is fairly similar to mind but with some changes. ( I give all credit to him for that) I may try your code as well just for extra measure :) Also as I am new to this, what you have stated about comparing the the two scanner class instances will help me as I have just seen that :) If I could leave reviews of your comments 5*'s :)

Answer (score 0):

Good to give yourself practice tasks!
Two things:
1) You only need one Scanner.
2) You'll have keep reference to the user input to compare the numbers (at least it would be a clean way) - use some int variables!

Like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

int var1 = scanner.nextInt();
int var2 = scanner.nextInt();

scanner.close();
if (var1 == var2) {
    System.out.println(var1 + " is equal to " + var2);
} else {
    System.out.println(var1 + " is not equal to " + var2);
}
```

And 3) Please read how to format your questions :)

Comment: In response to 1) Thank you for the information, me being new has lack of knowledge ;P 3) :P Yeah I wasn't very clear on formatting I had to change the wording many times and I was still not 100% when I published it :P